# nested input fields wont show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested, form-for

I have a nested two models nested in a form partial but the field_for part won't show up. I've been using nifty scaffolding. Any help is much appreciated!

**form partial**

```
    <%= form_for @lesson do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <% f.fields_for :glossaries do |build| %>
        <%= build.label :word_one, "Engelska" %> <br/>
        <%= build.text_field :word_one %>
        <%= build.label :word_two, "Svenska" %> <br/>
        <%= build.text_field :word_two %>
    <% end %>
  </p>
  <p><%= f.submit %></p>
<% end %>
```

**controller**

```
  def new
    @lesson = Lesson.new
    3.times { @lesson.glossaries.build }
  end
```

**glossary model**

```
    class Glossary < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :lesson_id, :word_one, :word_two
  belongs_to :lessons

end
```

**lesson model**

```
 class Lesson < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :word_one, :word_two
  has_many :glossaries, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :glossaries
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this directly copied and pasted from your source? If yes, there's a typo in your glossary model at line 3:

`belongs_to :lesson`, not `belongs_to :lessons`

Answer (score 0):

try this, write in your lesson model

```
attr_accessible :glossaries_attributes
```